# How to refer to descriptive information of variables as exogenous variables

Tags: publications, writing-style

I am writing the methodology section of my paper in management and one of the models I use takes descriptive statistics, such as min, max, mean, std, of entities as its input (classification model). However, I do not know how to refer to such input academically.

The way I have written it is:

> Our exogenous variables consisted of the descriptive information of
>   main variables and item pool characteristics. It allowed us not only
>   to rely on item side characteristics, but also on their
>   relative location in the environment space and relations to one
>   another.

How acceptable or academic is this? Should I explicitly refer to min max std etc. too? Or it is already clear to a reader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may depend on the field, but to me the phrase "the descriptive information of main variables and item pool characteristics" is utterly unclear. If you don't want to spell out the full set of descriptive statistical operators you use, consider including something like: "Our exogenous variables encompass [...] summary statistics over the main variables".

However, in the interest of reproducibility, I would personally prefer to spell out the full set. Right now, it is unclear to me how far you stretch up the set {min, max, mean, std}. There are so many things that could be included here: median, interquartile range, skewness, kurtosis, higher-order moments, etcetera. It's best to be explicit about your setup.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understood that being explicit must be preferred here. I changed my text to: `Our exogenous variables encompassed the following descriptive information of main variables and item pool characteristics: 1) mean, 2) standard deviation, 3) minimum, 4) maximum. It allowed us not only to rely on item side characteristics but also on their relative location in the environment space and relations to one another`. Do you think this would be explicit enough for my purposes?

Comment: That is a vast improvement, and likely implicit enough for your purposes.